# ng-model as an object for $validators

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I've been looking at a lot of examples for `$validators` and they all seem to do something along the lines of

```
value = modelValue | viewValue;
```

but what if I want my ng-model to be an object? does it make sense if the ng-model is an object? Most times you expect something like

```
$ctrl.myNgModelValue = 123` but if I were to do `$ctrl.myNgModelValue = {
  value: 123,
  label: 'hi'
}
```

that would mean inside my validator directive I would have to do something along the line of `value = viewValue[value] | modelValue[value]`.

Are there any downsides of using an object in the ng-model?

Comment: The [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) can handle models that are objects. Datepickers are an example of an input control that accepts and returns [Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).